# How to put Header 'behind' collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, header, collectionview

My collectionView has a header which is also a collectionView, the one in the header is for displaying photos. At the moment the header is on top of the background. How can I set it to go 'behind' the background so it looks like the image below. Also is it possible to round off the edges of the background to get the effect as seen on the right screenshot.
Im using Swift 3.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand of what are you trying to achieve. It sounds that you want sticky headers but I might be way too wrong with this one. For rounded corners set background to clear and add new view which will be your content holder. You will set corner radius for it and it will do the trick.

Comment: No, I'm not asking to do a sticky header. Okay so at the moment the header looks like it's 2D (the header goes on top of the collectionView background). What I want is to have that 3D effect where it looks like the header (image in the screenshot) is behind the collectionView and nav bar. (The whole view is a tableview controller with the image part as a header) @Luzo

Comment: Easiest way is to use view controller, add an image view to the top and add the collection view of full screen size. Then set the offset for first section. Don't forget to set background of collection view to clear.

Comment: The top part isn't an image, it's a collectionView as well with images in each cell and I also want to make it a stretchyHeader so it needs to be a header @Luzo

Comment: So then only option might be playing with size of image bigger than the cell(header) and turn off clips to bounds.